# Nginx redirect all requests trying to reach a folder

Tags: nginx, rewrite

How can I redirect all requests trying to reach a folder?

for example, I would like to redirect:

```
somedomain.com/folder/subfolder/index.html
somedomain.com/folder/subfolder2/something.html
somedomain.com/folder/subfolder3/somethingelse.html
```

to

```
somedomain2.com/index.html
```

what I've tried:

```
if ( $request_uri = "/folder/.*" ) {
  rewrite ^/(.*)$  http://domain2.com/embed.html    permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
server {
    server_name somedomain.com;

    location /folder/ {
        return 301 $scheme://somedomain2.com;
    }
}

server {
    server_name somedomain2.com;

    location / {
        #index index.html; # You could wish to add that, if index default value does not suits your needs
    }
}
```

That will issue a permanent redirect for any /folder/* request.

I took the liberty of mimicking the scheme being used with somedomain for somedomain2 with the [`$scheme`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_scheme) variable.

I have not forced the `/index.html` URI in the redirect. You may wish to do it. I also relied on the default value of the [`index`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) directive, which is maybe not right for you.

If you wished to handle the content from the other server transparently, you could use [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) to proxy the request to it.